# Data Extensions across Business Units? (no shared Data Extensions)

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is it possible to create Data Extensions with Data from Different Business Units? I don´t mean a simple Shared Data Extension, I mean: One Data Extension created from two different Synchronized Data Extensions which are stored in two different Business Units?

THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with the use of [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5).

Depending on your use case, you could write a SQL query to join data from the two data extensions based on predefined criteria and populate the results into a Shared Data extension. This [SQL query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) could be then automated and scheduled, for example, to run every day or every hour, or - since you mentioned Synchronized Data Extensions - even every 15 minutes, to ensure the latest data gets populated.

If you're Synchronized Data Extensions contain a large amount of data, you should also consider performance when setting up this automation.